# calculate Data rate at runtime in NS2

Tags: networking, tcl, ns2

am having simple topology of nodes in ns2 like

(1)------(2)-----(3)

where (1) is a source node and (3) is destination...I used CBR data traffic as the source with UDP agent..I want to calculate the data rate between the nodes (2) and (3) I know it is possible to calculate this using the trace file once the simulation is over

But my scenario is something like feedback system, I have to calculate the data rate between (2) and (3) if it is acceding some limit, I have to adjust the rate of the sender node (1), I looked in many example, but not found...Please share some example or how this can be done...thank you

Comment: I found [this example of how to do callbacks](http://samtrac.informatik.hu-berlin.de/brn/browser/BerlinRoofNet/simulation/ns2/ns-2.29-click/tcl/ex/callback_demo.tcl?rev=6) and thought it might be relevant. Except you'll want to do things other than just printing traces. (Remember to use the simulation time, not real time.) _This is not a proper answer_ but it might help anyway…

Comment: thank for the reply..will check it and try to modify